# Deleting pushes on github

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I pulled code from Github (commit #5) and worked on it, but in the mean time, other guys pushed commit #6 and #7 to Github. We decided to take only my work in consideration, which means that we don't need commits #6 and #7 anymore.

What can I do to delete the pushes of commits #6 and #7 from Github?

Comment: technically, you should revert them. If you are admin on the repo, you can reset the head to your head commit, and push -f.

Comment: why don't you push back your code again to override the pushed data, might work.

Comment: i get an error message asking me to pull before pushing, but i do'nt want to pull because i don't need the last commits on github

Comment: I deleted my answer with `git push origin master --force` for the moment because I don't want to let it stand there. I'm doing some further researches about this. Basically the problem with this way is if others have already pulled the code from the other guys, they got a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- the name of the branch in question is `master`
- the name of the remote is `origin`
- `origin/master` points to commit #7

then the following should work for you:

```
git push --force origin origin/master^^:master
```

#### Explanation of the arguments:

- `--force`:  By default, `git push` will only let you *advance* a branch -- the new commit must be a descendant of the old commit.  However, `--force` let's you override this safety check.  It will allow you to force a branch to point to any commit you want, even if it is topologically unrelated to where the branch is currently pointing.

  **Warning:**  If you need `--force`, you are rewriting history.  Rewriting history can cause all sorts of problems.  Before rewriting history, ensure that you and your teammates have a firm grasp on how Git works, and tell everyone that you are about to rewrite history.  If you don't, you're going to suffer consequences worse than the unpleasantness caused by `git revert`.
- `origin`: the name of the remote repository you are modifying
- `origin/master^^:master`:  This is called a *refspec*.  The part to the right side of the colon (`master`) is the name of the branch in the remote repository that you are trying to update.  The part to the left of the colon (`origin/master^^`) identifies the commit you want the remote branch to point to.  So in this case, you're telling Git that you want `origin`'s `master` branch to point to the same commit that `origin/master^^` points to in your local repository.  The `^^` after `origin/master` means "the first parent of the first parent", so `origin/master^^` refers to the grandparent of the commit that `origin/master` points to.  Given that `origin/master` is pointing to commit #7, `origin/master^^` should refer to commit #5.  Alternatively you can just use the SHA1 identifier for commit #5.

#### Details

Technically, this doesn't delete the commits from the remote repository.  It's not possible to delete commits without having filesystem-level access to the repository (i.e., you are employed at GitHub as a system administrator).  But it has the same effect:  nothing in the remote repository refers to the commits directly or indirectly, so they'll just sit there unreachable, wasting space until Git decides it's time to garbage collect them.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to take risks to run a complex git statements, jus ask the guys who have pushed the unwanted commits to run the following code:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

( the guy, who made commit #7 should run first), again
`git reset --hard HEAD^` ( the guy, who made commit #6 should run next ).

Now, you try to pull the code, and commit your local changes and push to git.

This might be silly...